# Editing a file with root privileges from python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, echo, tee

I am trying to make a python program write to a root protected file. This is using the python notify module. I am trying to get the program to use the registered endpoint.
On the console these both work and write sometext in the file /root/.config/notify-run:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo sometext >> /root/.config/notify-run'
echo sometext | sudo tee /root/.config/notify-run
```

Now in python I tried:

```
link = 'the endpoint'
command = ['sudo sh -c "echo', link, ' >>/root/.config/notify-run"']
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

This returns:

```
syntax error unterminated quoted string
```

And trying:

```
link = 'the endpoint'
command = ['echo', link, '| sudo tee -a /root/.config/notify-run'] 
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Returns no error but does not write the endpoint in the file.

Anyone knows how to fix this? using this or other code that does the same as i am trying to do over here?

Comment: You are missing a `]` in `command`

Comment: @FrozenAra You are right i forgot to type it in here in the code it was there just checked! Will edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string command rather than an array. This works to me:

```py
link = 'the endpoint'
command = 'echo ' + link + ' | sudo tee -a /root/.config/notify-run'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

However, I advice you to edit directly the `notify-run` file from your Python script and run the whole Python script with `root` privileges so you don't have to run `sudo`, unless your script does much more than writing to that file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This indeed works fine! Will mark you as the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Typing in `sudo`in your command would show the password prompt, and it would probably fail there.

The above answer asks you to run your script as root directly, however, if that's not possible, then you can move your script `sudo tee -a /root/.config/notify-run` into a different file.

Give it sudo access in `/etc/sudoers` file and execute it.

Comment: It does not fail, but it does show the password prompt.

Comment: Correct, my solution is just to workaround that, incase the user does not have adequate permission to run the entire python with root priviledges.

Comment: @MarcSances It does not promt me for the password. Maybe this is becasue the python programm is run with sudo